# IllegalArgumentException: Version must be >= 1, was 0. in Androis Studio with Room database

Tags: java, android-studio, android-room

I'm trying to persist a simple object that I I call QuesDto to a Room database.

I checked everything but couldn't figure out why I'm getting this exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1
    Process: ovh.lahmadi.naditutoadmin, PID: 7753
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Version must be >= 1, was 0
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.<init>(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        .......
```

Here is my Room Database abstract class:

```
@Database(entities = {QuesDto.class}, version = 0, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class QuizRoomDB extends RoomDatabase {

    private static volatile QuizRoomDB INSTANCE;
    public abstract QuizDao wordDao();
    .....

    public static QuizRoomDB getDatabase(Context context){
        if (INSTANCE == null){
            synchronized (QuizRoomDB.class){
                if (INSTANCE == null){
                        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), QuizRoomDB.class, "quiz_db")
                                .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

My Dao interface :

```
@Dao
public interface QuizDao {
    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void insert(QuesDto quesDto);
}
```

My Entity:

```
@Entity (tableName = "ques")
public class QuesDto {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private long quesId;
    private String quesHtml;
    ......
}
```

How I call the insert function:

```
    public QuestionRepository(Application application) {
        this.context = application.getApplicationContext();
        .....
    }

    public void saveQuesLocally(QuesDto quesDto) {
        QuizRoomDB db = QuizRoomDB.getDatabase(context);
        QuizDao quizDao = db.wordDao();
        Log.d(N.Room, "QuestionRepository. inside saveQuesLocally");
        new Thread(() -> {           
            QuizRoomDB.dbWriteExecutor.execute(()-> quizDao.insert(quesDto));
        }).start();
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is happening due to this internal logic:

```
 if (version < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Version must be >= 1, was " + version);
```

The SQLiteOpenHelper code is: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/74f170f9468d3cf6d7d0ef453320141a3e63571b/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java

You will need to change the version `1` in your class:

```
@Database(entities = {QuesDto.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class QuizRoomDB extends RoomDatabase {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@Database(entities = {QuesDto.class}, version = 0, exportSchema = false)
```

To

```
@Database(entities = {QuesDto.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
```

Check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int)) for more details.